# How to add custom field in managed package in visaulforce page?

Tags: managed-package, custom-field

I have custom page in managed package and I added one custom button in this page  when I click on this button I want to add one custom field in that page.  Can any one help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a custom field in an org where you package is installed and you want to show that on a page that's included in the package?

Comment: i have one button  when user click that button i want adding new field process then i want show that field in that vf page

Comment: If you actually want to create custom fields with a button on a VF page, I think you have to use the metadata API. It is possible to use the metadata API from an apex controller, but it will be complicated. See this link for the metadata API help: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/api_meta.pdf and this is a link to someone's implementation of it https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Answer (score 0):

Janardhan,

Your problem is still not clear.

But I think you want to show a custom field of an object on button click.

If above assumption is correct , then you can do like below

```
<apex:commandbutton action="{!toggleRender}" value="Show Field"/>
<apex:outputpanel id="fieldrender" render="{!checkRender}">
 <apex:inputfield value="{!object.fieldname}"/>
```

```
public boolean checkRender{get;set;} 
public void toggleRender(){
 checkRender = checkRender ? false :true;
```

}

Please explain your problem little more if my assumption is not correct.

please mark this as a answer if this solve your problem